# Inscribing a cylinder within a sphere

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Let's have a sphere with R=3. What is the trick to inscribe in this sphere a cylinder almost half
its volume? The circumferences of the two bases of the cylinder have to lie on the surface of the
sphere. All answers to contain the radius of cylinder and its height.

Comment: You're sure there is a *single* trick? (As indicated by the use of "**the** trick")

Comment: There is only one answer to this question.

Comment: Does "almost half" indicate exactly half, or less than half - and if the latter, how much less?

Comment: Indicates almost half.

Comment: This seems like a simple calculus problem, doesn't it?

Comment: @Pardy. Can you present your answer please.

Comment: Well, Axiomatic has presented a valid answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here's the view from one side of the cylinder and the sphere:
>  [image]

First,

> By Pythagorean's Theorem, $a^2+b^2=3^2=9$.

Then,

> we compare the volumes of the sphere and the cylinder:
> $V_{sphere}=\dfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3=36\pi$,
> $V_{cylinder}=\pi b^2 \cdot 2a=\dfrac{1}{2}V_{sphere}=18\pi$.
> Therefore, $ab^2=9$.

Now we can set up an equation:

> Since $a^2+b^2=9$, $b^2=9-a^2$, and we have the following cubic equation for $a$ : $a^3-9a+9=0$.
> Sadly, there are no rational roots to this equation. Using a calculator, we get $a=1.185$ or $a=2.227$.

And here is the answer:

> Therefore, there are two possible cylinders: one has a radius of 2.756 and a height of 2.370, the other has a radius of 2.010 and a height of 4.454.

Answer (score 1):

The desired cylinder has

> a radius of $2$ and a height of $2\sqrt{5}$.
>  Our sphere has volume $36\pi$, and our cylinder has volume $8\sqrt{5}\pi \approx 17\frac{8}{9}\pi$.

Comment: @ AxiomaticSystem. This not the correct answer